# What kind of protocol is used in android ToyVPN?

Tags: android, network-programming, android-vpn-service

In respect of [ToyVPN](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn) (a sample client/server VPN for android), as far as i know it has no strong authentication and encryption like L2TP,PPTP, ... So,


**1- What kind of protocol is used in `ToyVPN`?**
**2- Is it safe? I mean can somebody hack into the VPN tunnel?**
**3- if not safe; so what can i do to encrypt the tunnel?**
**4- Are the routers able to detect that this is a VPN tunnel? or is detected as a simple socket link?**